# How to delete specific piece of array?

Tags: php, mysqli

Okie dokie. Let's see if I can explain myself correctly. In two separate rows of my database, I have data that looks like this:

```
row1 (labeled "claimed") = Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4
row2 (labeled ctype) = Thing1, Thing2, Thing3, Thing4
```

I've pulled up the data so they group together like so:

```
Item1, Thing1
Item2, Thing2...
```

using this code:

```
<?php
$select=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `$table_members` WHERE email='$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]'");
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
    $name1=$row1['name'];
    $claim = $row1['claimed'];
    $type1 = $row1['ctype'];
    if ($claim != 'None') {
        $type2 = explode(', ', $type1);
        $decks = explode(', ', $claim);
        echo "<table id=\"memtable\"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Claimed</th><th>Type</th></tr>";
        foreach(array_combine($decks, $type2) as $deck => $type3){
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo "$name1</td><td>";
            echo "$deck</td><td>";
            echo "$type3</td><td>";
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

The problem now is that after a member submits a form I want to DELETE Item and Thing from the database based on their submission. So for example I have a dropdown showing

```
-Item1
-Item2...
```

They select Item2 and submit the form. Now I ONLY want to delete Item2 and Thing2 from my database, so now the rows would look like this:

```
row1 (labeled "claimed") = Item1, Item3, Item4
row2 (labeled ctype) = Thing1, Thing3, Thing4
```

I can't seem to figure out how to code it so that only the one particular instance is deleted. 
I assume it's something like the following:

```
foreach(array_combine($decks, $type2) as $deck => $type3){
$gone = "DELETE FROM `$table_members` WHERE claimed='$deck' AND ctype='$type3'";
            mysqli_query($connect, $gone);
}
```

ETA: I've found a solution! For anybody looking for the same type of thing here's what I did:

```
$remove = $_POST['remove;']

$select1=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `$table_members` WHERE email='$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]'");
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select1)) {
    $claim = $row1['claimed'];
    $type1 = $row1['ctype'];
}
$type2 = explode(', ', $type1);
$decks = explode(', ', $claim);
for($i=0;$i<count($decks);$i++){
    if($decks[$i]===$remove){unset($decks[$i]); unset($type2[$i]);}
}
$decks = implode(', ',$decks);
$type2 = implode(', ',$type2);
$gone = "UPDATE `$table_members` set claimed='$decks', ctype='$type2' where email='$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]'";
     mysqli_query($connect, $gone);
```

Comment: You *really* need to normalize your data.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really know how else to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand correctly your scenario.

The data in your table looks something like this:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Name   |  ctype                          |  claimed                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Jhon   | Thing1, Thing2, Thing3, Thing4  |  Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4 |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In that case if you just want to delete one item at the time, I think your best option will be:

```
$email = $_SESSION['USR_LOGIN'];
foreach(array_combine($decks, $type2) as $deck => $type3)
{
     $gone = "UPDATE `$table_members` set claimed=REPLACE(claimed,'$deck, ',''), ctype=REPLACE(ctype,'$type3, ', '') where email='$email'";
     mysqli_query($connect, $gone);
}
```

If you can post a sample of how the data is organized in your table I think I can provide a better example.

Comment: That is exactly how it is organized in the table. I've never used REPLACE before, so this is new territory for me. That almost worked, but when I tried to delete the second entry only it delted the first AND the second. We're almost there!

Comment: Actually, looking again, it got rid of every one except the very last one.